# Using 4 straight lines connect the stars together

Tags: logical-deduction, pattern

[image]

Using 4 straight lines connect these 9 stars together without lifting your pen from the surface. The end of each line must be start of the next line.

Comment: This is a fairly standard puzzle, so lots of people will probably already know the answer. If I may make a suggestion - if you do already know at a glance, don't answer, let those who haven't seen it have a proper go at it.

Comment: And to those who haven't seen this puzzle before, I just thought I'd say that you have to think outside the box to solve it.

Comment: I feel like I've seen this on this site before, but can't find it.

Answer (score 6):

Is it valid that 2 of the corners are beyond the stars?

Here's my attempt!

[image: Attempt]

Comment: This is the most common answer to this children's puzzle.

Answer (score 5):

I've never seen this one before, but here's what jumps out at me:
[image]

Comment: I guess, but the "standard" puzzle that Glen references earlier in the comments basically assumes that the lines must pass through the centers of the stars/points/whatever.

Comment: Doesn't the second one not pass through the leftmost star?

Comment: @Reticality It does look that way, doesn't it? *scratches head*

Comment: It just might work in Lobachevskian geometry.

Comment: I love your first solution! The puzzle is about "thinking outside the box" (literally:)) and you took it to the next level with just 3 lines, nice! (The second solution is indeed faulty.)

Answer (score 3):

Using the information from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_(geometry)#Extension_to_non-Euclidean_geometry:

> 2. parallel, if they do not intersect in the plane, but have a common limit point at infinity, or [...]

So, if we put this in a non-Euclidean plane, it can be done with one line:

[image: One line]

But, of course, this would take forever to draw (But it *does* pass through the centres of all stars)

---

I can also confirm it is impossible to do on a Euclidean plane without going outside the box with [this](http://pastebin.com/W13GZnVs) Python script.

There are 84 different ways to do it with 5 lines inside the box, but that should be around 11 unique ones because most are reflected or rotated.